# In java my toString() is not working as I expected

Tags: java, tostring

I have this code and thought that the `toString()` that I overrides would fire in both sub and superclass

```
public class Person  {
    @Override
    public String toString(){
       System.out.printLn("im in Person  ");
       return "im in Person  ";
    }
}

public class Student extends Person {
    @Override
    public String toString(){

       System.out.printLn("im in Student");
       return "im in Student";
    }
}


Student s = new Student();

System.out.println(s.toString());
```

Comment: `System.out.printLn` is not a method. But you need to _return_ a string from `toString()`, not try to print it.

Comment: Please return some values. It seems method not return anything

Comment: It should output two lines, each "im in Student".

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In object-oriented terms, overriding means to override the functionality of an existing method.
At the runtime, JVM figures out the object type and would run the method that belongs to that particular object.
Therefore, in your example, at the runtime, the programs runs the method specific for the Student object.

If you need to call the method from the super class, then you need to do it by yourself by calling `super.toString()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Person  {
    @Override
    public String toString(){
       return "im in Person  ";
    }
}

public class Student extends Person {
    @Override
    public String toString(){
         return String.format("%s\n%s", super.toString(), "im in Student");
    }
}
```

And you can call it as you were doing.